# Copyright issues with combining JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript

Say my web application uses jQuery, and I combine jQuery's source file with my own JavaScript files into a single file.

Now, I still have to put jQuery's copyright header at the top of the combined file, right? But do I also have to add a notice that I "modified" this file as I have added my own code?

What if I'm using multiple JavaScript libraries and have combined all of them, as well as my own code, into a single file? Do I dump all their copyright headers at the top and add a modification notice? Would it be legal?

And a related question, do I have to also include a copy of all the related licenses in my website? If so, how are major websites handling this? For example, StackOverflow uses jQuery, where is its page containing the MIT or GPLv2 license?

Comment: I'm not sure that including multiple libraries in one file even counts as modification. I wouldn't think you'd necessarily want to move all of the copyright notices to the top, either, I'd be more inclined to leave them at the top of their own section. Note that jQuery's licence explicitly allows you to "merge" it.

Comment: Regarding your last question, I would say you _have_ already included the notices in your website, within your JS include file(s). Most users won't see the notice of course, but all users in a position to actually infringe on the copyright _will_ see it. There's no reason to display license notices prominently where _all_ users will see them (except in the case of really weird license agreements).

Comment: Make sure you put some kind of header on your own code too, so that it doesn't look like it belongs to one of the other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea of the legal issues, but accepted practice is to put a copyright comment block before each piece of open source code. At flickr we use YUI, and put this block before includes YUI code in our combined files:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.
Code licensed under the BSD License:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html
version: 3.3.0
build: 3167
*/
```

As you can see it includes a link to the license, copyright information and a description of the license.